# Merge and sum two pandas rows based on if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a huge dataframe and i want to **`merge only two rows in it based on if condition`**. Below is a sample data frame and when I tried to do `groupby sum` other rows are also getting effected.

I only want column `jb_name` with `generic` to get `merged and sum`.

```
    jb_name   jb_count
0   generic    10
1   generic1    2
2   generic    15
3   other      14
```

tried the following but as i said its effecting other rows as well

```
df = df.groupby(['jb_name'])['jb_count'].sum().reset_index()
```

I want the final df as following

```
    jb_name   jb_count
0   generic    25
1   generic1    2
3   other      14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mask = df['jb_name'] == 'generic'
df = df[mask].groupby('jb_name', as_index=False).sum().append(df[~mask], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: i have updated the final df that i want... i am really sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can set the index to `jb_name` and use `sum` on `level 0` where index is `generic`:

```
df = df.set_index('jb_name')
mask = (df.index == 'generic')
df1 = pd.concat([df[mask].sum(level=0), df[~mask]]).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

    jb_name  jb_count
0   generic        25
1  generic1         2
2     other        14
```

Comment: I want other rows as well... My bad that I made it little unclear

Comment: Please edit the question with your expected output..

Comment: Thanks shubham...I have updated...Can you please check again

Answer (score 0):

```
#Bollean select, droupby as you sum the duplicated and append tthe no duplicates

m=df.jb_name=='generic'
df[m].groupby(by='jb_name', axis=0).sum().reset_index().append(df[~m])



jb_name  jb_count
0   generic        25
1  generic1         2
3     other        14
```